# React Leaflet Collision

Tags: react-leaflet

I am using map without any label of town. I am putting the labels, i need these labels appear and dissapear on zoom in/out. When zoom out appear only big towns when zoom in appear all towns. Is there fuctionality for this in existing react-leaflet?
Also i am trying make plugin for Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision,
I tried overriding LayerGroup from react-leaflet

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { MapLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import { layerGroup } from 'leaflet';
import './leaflet-layergroup-collision';

export default class LayerGroupCollision extends MapLayer {
  static childContextTypes = {
    layerContainer: PropTypes.shape({
      addLayer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      removeLayer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    })
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      layerContainer: this.leafletElement,
    }
  }

  createLeafletElement() {
    return layerGroup(this.getOptions()).collision({margin:5});
  }
}
```

But i am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _leaflet.layerGroup)(...).collision is not a function

Any help how implement this or any alternative idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layerGroup should be with capital L, LayerGroup

```
import { LayerGroup } from 'leaflet';
```

or an alternative try:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
```

and then

```
L.LayerGroup(this.getOptions()).collision({margin:5});
```

Comment: Hi, if this fixed the error you were having in the question you should accept the answer. Thank you!